# Should I call services directly when i use NGRX?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, redux, ngrx

Does NGRX have any opinion about using services in components directly?

**Example:**

Login Component: Versions how to handle the login:

- Dispatch a Login Action when the user clicks the Login Button and let an AuthEffect handle the communication with the server
- Call the Login Method of the AuthService directly in the Login component and dispatch a Login Action in the callback that gets called, when the server has returned a response.

Are there any significant advantages or disadvantages here that I overlook? Or is it up to me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use **Facades** to handle interactions with the store for more simplicity and to eliminate the  difficulties of maintaining and scaling, check [this](https://frontend.consulting/abstracting-state-with-ngrx-facades)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not call a service in your component because your component will be depend on the service and when your application growth big you will have a problem to maintain your code

Using ngrx to dispatch an action in your component so that effect will handle a service call will be best practice because you are not depend on the service you just dispatch an action and effect will take care the rest for you

Comment: But how would you handle this scenario: By clicking a button, I create a new ToDo Item and send it to the server. When the server responds with a success response, I want to display a success alert. Where does the component know from, when to display the alert?

Comment: You should do in effect